# Microsoft Graph API 502 Bad Gateway when trying to archive a Team

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I get a 502 Bad Gateway when I try to archive a Microsoft Team :

```
Server error: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/b6557192-0afd-4839-b1a7-fc1b0b452bdc/archive` resulted in a `502 Bad Gateway` response:{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadGateway",
    "message": "Failed to execute backend request.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "d835ede5-b70a-4d5b-952f-e5152609d0d5",
      "date": "2020-04-27T15:20:06"
    }
  }
}
```

I send the follwing data as the POST body :

```
{
    "shouldSetSpoSiteReadOnlyForMembers": true
}
```

I use delegated permissions and I am owner of this Team.

Anyone ever had this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that when you create a Team and you don't click on the `Files` tab in Microsoft Teams, if you call this endpoint with the `"shouldSetSpoSiteReadOnlyForMembers": true` parameter, you will get this error. If you click the `Files` tab once, and then call the archive endpoint, you will get a `HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted` response.

Hope this will help someone, took me some time to figure this out, this API always returns generic error messages which doesn't help the developer.

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me. Thanks, you saved me lots of time.